# Behat doesn't load extensions?

Tags: php, testing, bdd, behat

I've installed behat and mink as described here http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html,

This is my behat.yaml

```
# behat.yml
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
```

Also I've added *search.feature* in *features* folder.

But when I do

```
/bin/behat features/search.feature
```

I receive

```
....
2 scenarios (2 undefined)
8 steps (8 undefined)
0m0.032s
...
```

When I do

```
/bin/behat -dl
```

I receive nothing in response! It drives me crazy, please help. This is something related to paths, but I have no idea how I should handle it.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me. Configuration name should be behat.**yml**, not behat.**yaml**